# How to install beautifulsoup4 for python 3 with pip, confused

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I keep seeing answers saying that I should install it with pip with:

```
$ pip install beautifulsoup4
```

But quite frankly I'm not knowledgeable enough to know what that's supposed to mean. Do I have to run it in the cmd? If I try that it just gives me an error about $ not being an external or internal command. I am completely lost. Please help.

Comment: You may wish to start with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows - then - you should be able to proceed to installing your module

Comment: `pip` is an external add-on for Python. Read the [documentation](http://www.pip-installer.org/) and make sure you have it installed first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see instructions that instruct you to:

```
$ some_shell_command arg1 arg2
```

all the `$` is saying is "run this in a shell (or, on Windows, a Command Prompt), as your normal user." You don't need to include the `$` in the command -- that's the error you're seeing.

The source of this notation: by default, the `bash` shell command prompt ends with a `$`, e.g. `user@host:~$`.

Comment: They're on Windows... so might be a little clearer to use `Command Prompt` here...

Comment: Oh, that's what had me confused. I had no idea that $ meant that. I managed to install it, but unfortunately I'm getting the 'ImportError: No module named 'html.entities'; html is not a package' error. The error happens after running: 'from bs4 import BeautifulSoup'

Comment: Check this out. Unfortunately, the fix sounds like a bit of a pain: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#problems-after-installation

Comment: Thanks, I guess I can handle some more pain. :)

Answer (score 0):

try 
`pip install bs4`
and import beautifulsoup from bs4